# xml get parent and element name

Tags: xml, parent

I have an xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<common>
  <p>
    <alias>mval1</alias>
    <endpoint-address>abc</endpoint-address>
  </p>
  <g>
    <alias>mval2</alias>
    <endpoint-address>def</endpoint-address>
  </g>
  <b>
    <alias>mval3</alias>
    <endpoint-address>hij</endpoint-address>
  </b>
</common>
```

What should be my xpath expression to get output like:

```
p: "abc"
g: "def"
b: "hij"
```

Comment: What is your XPath version?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try following XPath expression?

```
.//common/*/concat(./name(), ' : ', ./endpoint-address/text())
```